# The store that was requested wasn't found

Tags: magento2, nginx

I just made new magento2 project. I got this:

> Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: The store that was
>   requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.

I copied nginx config file from another project. I suppose problem is here:

```
map $request_uri $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
     default uk_view;
    ~^/ger/.* test_view;
}
```

These are wrong stores for this project.
I've deleted it , but still same error. 
What should be default **map** `$request_uri $MAGE_RUN_CODE {}`